# Regular expression match decimal with letters

Tags: regex

I have following string 3.14, 123.56f, .123e5f, 123D, 1234, 343E12, 32.
What I want to do is match any combination of above inputs. So far I started with the following:

```
^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)
```

I realize I have to escape the . since its a regular expression itself.

Thanks.

Comment: What languag eare you using the regex from?

Comment: Do you know why use sometimes use `[0-9]` and sometimes `\d`?

Comment: It isn't clear the `D` what is and what modifiers it's compatible with

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `above inputs`?

Comment: @xanatos I was actually trying to figure a generic regex but mainly this for java and in the sense of floating point numeric constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should also work, if not already proposed.

```
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\.?\\b[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?[fD]?\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        // matched text: regexMatcher.group()
        // match start: regexMatcher.start()
        // match end: regexMatcher.end()
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably

```
^(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)([eE]\d+)?[fD]?$
```

http://regexr.com?2ut9t

```
^ start of the string
(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+) one or more digits with an optional ( . and one or more digits)
  or
. and one or more digits
([eE]\d+)? an optional ( e or E and one or more digits)
[fD]? an optional f or D
$ end of the string
```

As a sidenote, I've made the `D` compatible with everything but the `f`.

If you need positive and negative sign, add `[+-]?` after the `^`

Comment: Yes, but you used non capturing groups, and your regex will succeed for empty string (you have everything optional)

Comment: Everyone that uses Regexes loses before or later! :-) :-) This is the only hard truth.

Answer (score 2):

This will match all of those:

```
[0-9.]+(?:[Ee][0-9.]*)?[DdFf]?
```

Note that within a character class (square brackets), dot `.` is not a special character and should not be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that one ?

```
^\d*(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE]\d+)?(?:[fD])?$
```

with

```
^\d*         #possibly a digit or sequence of digits at the start
(?:\.\d+)?    #possibly followed by a dot and at least one digit
(?:[eE]\d+)?  #possibly a 'e' or 'E' followed by at least one digit
(?:[fD])?$    #optionnaly followed by 'f' or 'D' letters until the end
```

Comment: Caution: as xanatos pointed above: this will also holds true for empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) to test it out, but this seems to work on all of those examples:

```
^\d*\.?(\d*[eE]?\d*)[fD]?$
```